# How to hide table rows based on child class name using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, classname

I have a lot of rows and I want to hide some tr that doesn't have a specific class.

Example:

```
<tr id="game-22590" class="game">
    <td class="pos left-edge">
        <div>2</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cost">
        <input class="dollars-paid uncorrected" type="text" value="19,99" tabindex="4">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="game-22591" class="game">
    <td class="pos left-edge">
        <div>3</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cost">
        <input class="dollars-paid" type="text" value="23,99" tabindex="4">
    </td>
</tr>
```

The td.cost has an input with a class or two. I want to hide those rows that doesn't have the `uncorrected` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to selecting rows has `uncorrected` class.

```
$("tr.game").filter(function(){
    return $(this).find("input.uncorrected").length == 0;
}).hide();
```

```js
$("tr.game").filter(function(){
    return $(this).find("input.uncorrected").length == 0;
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="game-22590" class="game">
    <td class="pos left-edge">
      <div>2</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cost">
      <input class="dollars-paid uncorrected" type="text" value="19,99" tabindex="4">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="game-22591" class="game">
    <td class="pos left-edge">
      <div>3</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cost">
      <input class="dollars-paid" type="text" value="23,99" tabindex="4">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with closest() method jQuery... please check this solution

```js
$(".dollars-paid").not(".uncorrected").closest(".game").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="game-22590" class="game">
    <td class="pos left-edge">
        <div>2</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cost">
        <input class="dollars-paid uncorrected" type="text" value="19,99" tabindex="4">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="game-22591" class="game">
    <td class="pos left-edge">
        <div>3</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cost">
        <input class="dollars-paid" type="text" value="23,99" tabindex="4">
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="game-22592" class="game">
    <td class="pos left-edge">
        <div>3</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cost">
        <input class="dollars-paid" type="text" value="25,99" tabindex="4">
    </td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table tr.game").each(function(){
    var self=$(this);
    if(!self.find("input").hasClass("uncorrected")){
        self.hide();
    }
});
```

[Working DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3L3rw5u9/2/)